# Test settings for mailoptions (for bolt_auth)

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm building a bolt cms site on my local development environment (MAMP Pro 5.7).  I've added the bolt_auth extension for frontend permissions and authentication.

My site is broken with bolt_auth installed.  I think it needs a valid configuration for mailoptions in config.yml.  I don't know how to fill this out successfully:

```
mailoptions:
    transport: smtp
    spool: true
    host: ????
    port: ??
    username: ***@*****.com
    password: ******
    encryption: null
    auth_mode: null
    senderMail: null
    senderName: null
```

What should I use here for my test setup?  I went to SparkPost as suggested in the comments of config.yml, but even the free account requires a valid domain with a valid website published to it.  I don't want to do any of this for my test environment.  I just want it to work enough for me to build and test my site.  Deployment comes later.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://mailtrap.io/ instead of sparkpost.